# custom jQuery not working with featherlight.js

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I seem to be having an issue executing jquery within a window that is displayed via featherlight.js.

Its almost as if featherlight disables jquery as it relates to content that appears within the lightbox window.

I'm trying to utilize the jQuery Autocomplete plugin and I have a fiddle that shows it working when embedded on the page but not working with utilizing featherlight.

```
<a href="#" data-featherlight="#fl1">click to open lightbox</a>
<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">
<div class="mylightbox">Not Working: <input class="autocomplete"></div>
</div></div></div></div>
<div class="mylightbox">Working: <input class="autocomplete">'try "php"'</div>
<script>
$( ".autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/194/

Any direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your version of Featherlight is ancient. Please always update to a current version before asking for help!

Comment: thanks for the info. I've updated the fiddle with 1.7.12.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `data-featherlight-persist=true` doesn't quite do the trick. `autocomplete` seems to be assuming that the elements won't be moved afterwards.

You'll instead have to call the `autocomplete` within the `afterContent` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The updated fiddle has the code changes that you recommended but still no luck. Do you know of an example that is using featherlight and also incorporating jQuery that I can review?